# Support additional mime types in hapi

Tags: mime-types, content-type, hapi.js, graphql

I am working on a graphql + relay app served on top of hapi and would like to support requests to the graphql endpoint with the `application/graphql` mime type.

Here you can see me sending POST requests to the graphql endpoint.

```
~> curl -X POST --header "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"query":"{content(id:\"13381672\"){title,id}}"}' http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphql
{"data":{"content":{"title":"Example Title","id":"13381672"}}}

~> curl -X POST --header "Content-Type:application/graphql" -d '{"query":"{content(id:\"13381672\"){title,id}}"}' http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphql
{"statusCode":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type"}
```

I do not see any place in my hapi server options where there is any explicit configuration for mime types and other than some terse documentation [here](http://hapijs.com/api#servermime).

I have set up an options mime configuration as per the below, passing options into the server instantiation, but I am still seeing the `"Unsupported Media Type"` error.

```
options.mime = {
  override: {
    'application/graphql': {
      charset: 'UTF-8',
      compressible: true,
      type: 'application/graphql'
    }
  }
};
```

Does anybody else here have this kind of experience with hapi?

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful but in this example (https://github.com/SimonDegraeve/hapi-graphql/blob/master/src/index.js) the author created a new handler which checks for mime type.

Comment: Sure...I have actually ported (modified) this code for my hapi server, and it works fine for the most part. We see here (https://github.com/SimonDegraeve/hapi-graphql/blob/master/src/index.js#L64) that the author is checking for the mime-type (as do I). But the issue I have is I do not see where/how to register this additional non-standard mime type.

My cURL (above) with the `application/graphql` type does not even make it through to the `parsePayload()` function. It is being thrown out with a 415 error long before that.

Comment: Are you still having this issue? That should work.

Comment: I'm not having any direct issues, as I learned that my relay front end is making requests of a standard mime-type. At some point I would still like how to teach hapi to accept non-standard types, but this is a non-issue for me, now.

Answer (score 2):

Each route has a `payload` config option which takes an `allow` property that lets hapi know which mimetypes to allow for that route. If you set it to `application/graphql`, and the `parse` option to `false`, your requests will work.

Unfortunately, you'll have to parse the payload yourself.

Here's an example route:

```
server.route({
  method: ['POST', 'PUT'],
  path: '/graphql',
  config: {
    payload: {
      parse: false,
      allow: 'application/graphql'
    }
  },
  handler: function(request, reply) {
    reply(request.payload)
  }
})
```